# WooCommerce doesn't show actual price on cart page without tax

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, tax

I have build webstore on WooCommerce. I have added standard tax rate when the customer fills their billing address and select country tax will be applied on the checkout page that is working fine I want to show actual price of products on cart page without multiply my tax ratio with my product price

> **This is checkout page show tax when a country is selected**

[image: This is checkout page show tax when a country is selected]

> **this is cart page showing tax calculated value and grand total show without tax value**

[image: this is cart page showing tax calculated value and grand total show without tax value]

I have added this function in my function.php file but no success

```
    function wc_remove_cart_tax_totals( $tax_totals, $instance ) {

    if( is_cart() ) {
        $tax_totals = array();
    }

    return $tax_totals;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_tax_totals', 'wc_remove_cart_tax_totals', 10, 2 );

// Show the cart total excluding tax.
function wc_exclude_tax_cart_total( $total, $instance ) {

    // If it is the cart subtract the tax
    if( is_cart() ) {

        $total = round( WC()->cart->cart_contents_total + WC()->cart->shipping_total + WC()->cart->fee_total, WC()->cart->dp );

    }

    return $total;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'wc_exclude_tax_cart_total', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_calculated_total', 'wc_exclude_tax_cart_total', 10, 2 );
```